# Distinguish between iPad and mac on iPad with iOS 13+

Tags: ios, ipad, ios13, user-agent, ios14

Since iOS 13 iPads identify themselves as Macs in the user agent.

Unfortunately I have a web service that ***DOES NOT WORK*** on an iPad. It is not my service, not my code, and I can't have any detection or redirection done in that service so checking for touch isn't an option. I really need to redirect from .htaccess as any code that runs after that is outside of my control.

Is there any way for me to redirect iPads to a different site without redirecting actual Macs?

Comment: I'll upvote this, but I'm guessing you won't get a useful answer. Maybe you could detect it's an iPad **or** a Mac and let the user decide what to do? Web sites (or services) generally *shouldn't* care about this... why does your's? And since it's not your code/service, any chance you could directly ask the owner?

Comment: Apple did this intentionally because they didn't want you to redirect users to a different site since you are supposed to treat an iPad as a desktop browser.

Comment: @alison - RFC 1945 states user agents are for "automated recognition of user agents for the sake of tailoring responses to avoid particular user agent limitations". This service doesn't work on the iPad due to user agent limitations. Apple crying about developers treating them differently doesn't solve the problem of them being different.